# Spotify APIs: error when trying to add a track to a playlist for the first time, the second attempt works

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, spotify-app

I getting this error when adding a track to a playlist for the first time:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined core.js:598
```

Then I run the script again, and it works!!! :-o

The code is relatively armless and you can see it at [this URL](https://github.com/giacecco/s08etulosbA-Radio/blob/f2da66e27703e81b67bff30db02494851741d482/index.html#L96).

Is this happening to anybody else? Any ideas?

G.

Answer (score 0):

I have studied the Spotify API documentation further and found out that a new API set marked as version '1.0.0' is available. It is likely that issues with the older API sets are not going to be supported, hence it is not useful to address them here or elsewhere. I ported my code to the new APIs.

Giacecco